# char[] manipulation in C

Tags: c, char, pic

Suppose I define the following:

```
unsigned char temp[2][13];
```

What is the default values will be assign to this `char[]`? Is it like `{'', '', '', ... , ''}`?

In my program (The calculator), I have `operand[2][13]` (where first operand is `operand[0]` and second operand is `operand[1]`) and I have Operation and `Result[15]` and they are all `unsigned char`. Fisrt, the user will enter Operand1 and Operand2 (A char at a time) and it will be stores in `operand[2][13]` then the program will store the result as chars in `Result[15]`. Now what I want is, at next iteration, I want to clear `operand[2][13]`, operation and `Result[15]` so that the user can enter next operands and the program executes next operation and saves the result in `Result[15]`.

How can I clear these arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)`(operand, 0, 2 * 13);`
[`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)`(Result, 0, 15);`

Answer (score 2):

No default values.  None at all.  Make sure you set them yourself.  Here's one handy form:

```
unsigned char temp[2][13] = {0};
```

Answer (score 2):

`''` is not a value. In fact, it does not make sense to specify an "empty" character.

Usually the data is not initialized for you. The data will be whatever was in the memory before you allocated it. The exception is if this is static data, then is should be zero'd out ('\0').

You should generally plan on initializing such data yourself using a function such as `memset()`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context where it is defined.

If it is declared out of a function (globally), it will reside in the `.bss` section of the executable and the operating system will initialise the whole array to zero on program startup, before `main` is invoked.

If it's declared locally (on the stack) it will contain whatever garbage is there and then you can either initialise it with `memset` or with the appropriate array initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is no default value assigned to the array elements (and it's undefined behaviour to read the values) or 0 (zero) is assigned, depending on exactly how and where the array is defined.

global and static arrays are initialized to 0 (zero)

```
unsigned char aglobal[2][13]; /* all zeroes */
int foo(void) {
    static unsigned char astatic[2][13]; /* all zeroes */
    unsigned char aauto[2][13]; /* unset, ub to read values */
}
```

You can initialize with your preference though

```
unsigned char tmp[2][13] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {11}};
```

The above initialization has the effect that all elements are 0 (zero) except `tmp[0][0]` to `tmp[0][4]` and `tmp[1][0]`.

Or set the elements one by one in the middle of your code, after initialization:

```
for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
    for (k=0; k<13; j++) {
        tmp[j][k] = 0;
    }
}
```